# 2nd Function not executing - suitescript

Tags: function, email, scheduled-tasks, netsuite, suitescript

I have the below code. I want the function called execute2 to run after the function execute. When I put the script task inside the first function and don't include execute2 then it all runs fine and the second separate script runs. But when I run it in the below format it does not. What is preventing execute 2 from actually running here?

Thank you

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
 
 define(['N/task'],
 
 /**
 * @param {record} record
 * @param {search} search
 */
 
 function(task) {
 
 var FILE_ID = 433961; 
 var SEARCH_ID = 1610;
 
 function execute(scriptContext) {
 
 var searchTask1 = task.create({
 taskType: task.TaskType.SEARCH
 
 });
 
 searchTask1.savedSearchId = SEARCH_ID;
 searchTask1.fileId = FILE_ID;
 
 var searchTaskId1 = searchTask1.submit();
 //
 //Next Task
 //
 FILE_ID = 433963;
     SEARCH_ID = 1606;
     var searchTask2 = task.create({
         taskType: task.TaskType.SEARCH
     });
 
     searchTask2.savedSearchId = SEARCH_ID;
     searchTask2.fileId = FILE_ID;
     var searchTaskId2 = searchTask2.submit();
 //
 //Next Task
 //
   FILE_ID = 434489;
     SEARCH_ID = 1637;
     var searchTask3 = task.create({
         taskType: task.TaskType.SEARCH
     });
 
     searchTask3.savedSearchId = SEARCH_ID;
     searchTask3.fileId = FILE_ID;
     var searchTaskId3 = searchTask3.submit();
 //
 // Next Task
 //
   FILE_ID = 434490;
     SEARCH_ID = 1606;
     var searchTask4 = task.create({
         taskType: task.TaskType.SEARCH
     });
 
     searchTask4.savedSearchId = SEARCH_ID;
     searchTask4.fileId = FILE_ID;
     var searchTaskId4 = searchTask4.submit();
 
 }
 
 function execute2(scriptContext){
 
      var scriptTask = task.create({
       taskType: task.TaskType.SCHEDULED_SCRIPT,
       scriptId: "customscript_email_sender",
       deploymentId: "customdeploy_email_sender_d"
     });
 
     var scriptTaskId = scriptTask.submit();
 
 }
 
 return {
 
   
   execute: execute,
   execute2: execute2,
 
 };
 
 });
```

Comment: You should read the documentation in NetSuite. A scheduled script has only a single trigger point called `execute`. Everything else which you return in the object, won't trigger anything. https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4407979858.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on [the comment from W.S.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74769167/2nd-function-not-executing-suitescript#comment131959888_74769167), all you need to do is to define two functions that encapsulate your business logic and then call those functions in order within your scheduled script's entry point.

Below is a simple example, showing the scheduled script executing `doFirstTask()` followed by `doSecondTask()`. You can redefine those however you like to meet your own needs.

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */
 define([], function() {
  return {
    execute: function (context)
    {
      doFirstTask(context);
      doSecondTask(context);
    }
  }
});

/**
 * This function contains all of the logic you need to execute
 * for the first of your two tasks.
 * 
 * @param context Passed in from the scheduled script's entry point.
 */
function doFirstTask(context) {
  log.debug({
    title: context.type + ': First Task',
    details: 'The first of many great feats.'
  });
}

/**
 * This function contains all of the logic you need to execute
 * for the second of your two tasks.
 * 
 * @param context Passed in from the scheduled script's entry point.
 */
function doSecondTask(context) {
  log.debug({
    title: context.type + ': Second Task',
    details: 'Second, even more impressive than the first.'
  });
}
```

Here's a screenshot showing what the output looks like.

[image: log.debug output from scheduled script]

Comment: Incredible work, thank you